# More variables than values error

Tags: fortran

My program starts like

```
implicit real*8 (a-h,o-z)
parameter (pi=3.141592654)
real*4 yfl
real*4 zz0(20),a0(20),fr0(20)
real*4 par_ion(6)
```

but I later get error messages such as the below.

```
data fr0/0.780,0.209,0.009,3*0./     ! fraction by mass for elemen
    1
Error: DATA statement at (1) has more variables than values
music-atmosphere-100gev.f:82.10:

data a0/14.0097,15.9994,39.948,3*0./     ! atomic weights for elem
    1
Error: DATA statement at (1) has more variables than values
music-atmosphere-100gev.f:81.10:

data zz0/7.,8.,18.,3*0./    ! atomic numbers for elements in atmos
    1
Error: DATA statement at (1) has more variables than values
```

Can anyone help me figure out what is going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From

```
real*4 zz0(20),a0(20),fr0(20)
```

You can see that `fr0`, `a0`, and `zz` have a dimension of `20`. So the correct initialization(s) should read:

```
data fr0/0.780,0.209,0.009,17*0./
data a0/14.0097,15.9994,39.948,17*0./
data zz0/7.,8.,18.,17*0./
```

This way, you assign arrays of length 20 (three values and 17 times zero) instead of the previous length-6 arrays.

Comment: Thank you!!! I am not a Fortran programmer, I am simply modifying a simulation code that was given to me. I did not pick up on the significance of the number times 0.

Answer (score 3):

When using a `data` statement for explicit initialization it is required that the number of elements in the two parts (the *variables* before the first `/` and the *values* between the two `/`s) be the same.

In this case a whole array is given for each first part so each list there consists of all of the elements of the corresponding array (of which there are twenty).  Therefore, there must be twenty elements of values (as [Alexander Vogt gives](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32554149)).

To add to that answer, though, it isn't erroneous not to initialize the whole array.  One could instead have

```
data fr0(1:6)/0.780,0.209,0.009,3*0./
```

which provides explicit initialization for the first six elements of `fr0`.  [In this case `fr0` as an array isn't defined initially, just its first six elements.]  This is useful when one has a long lump of initialization to do:

```
 data fr0(1:6)/0.780,0.209,0.009,3*0./
 data fr0(7:12)/0.780,0.209,0.009,3*0./
 ...
```

etc., or if one really cares only about the first six elements (say when the lengths varies between compilations, but the first elements are important)